# Как в определенные строки в .txt файле записывать информацию, а затем читать ее и перезаписывать?

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать систему сохранения для игры, нужно записывать определенные переменные и списки в один .txt файл, а после запуска читать информацию с определенных строк файла. Как это сделать?
Пример информации которая должна быть внутри файла:

```
1
7034
64
"test", "..."
764
```

Нужно каждый этот параметр записать в отдельную пременную.

Comment: Не очень понятно в чем проблема. Несложно загуглить статью про работу с файлами в питоне. Там будет рассказано как читать из файла и записывать в файл.

Comment: @rew проблема в том, что я не понимаю как считывать или записывать информацию в определенных строках в файле

Comment: Вроде нет такой команды поменять определенную строку файла. Но кто мешает вам самим ее написать? Считываете массив строк, меняете в массиве конкретные строки, записываете в файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странный выбор сохранять данные в файле, для этого принято использовать базы данных, но да ладно. Записать/извлечь информацию в файле можно таким образом:

```
import json


path_to_file = '...'


def write_data(data):
    """ Функция для записи информации в файл.
    Если в файле уже есть какая-то информация, то она перезаписывается
    Принимает 1 аргумент - словарь с информацией, которую нужно записать"""

    # открывем наш файл, второй аргумент указывает,
    # что файл открывается для записи в него чего либо
    f = open(path_to_file, 'w')
    # записываем в него что-то. Данные преобразуем в json
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
    # закрываем файл
    f.close()


def read_data():
    """ функция для извлечения информации из файла. Возвращает словарь с информацией """

    # открывем наш файл, второй аргумент указывает,
    # что файл открывается для чтения информации из него
    f = open(path_to_file, 'r')
    # Читаем информацию из файла и преобразуем её из json в словарь
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    # закрываем файл
    f.close()
    # возвращаем данные
    return data
```

Comment: А как записать каждую переменную в определенной строке в json файле а при следующем запуске, информацию из каждой строки считать в определенную переменную?

Comment: @OMEGA чем вас словарь не угодил?

Comment: ок, допустим, я записал словарь со всеми переменными в файл, а как после этого каждую строчку считать в отдельную переменную?

Comment: @OMEGA функция `read_data` вернёт вам словарь, который вы записали

Comment: а как именно эта функция считает данные с файла? Как простой текст или со свойствами словаря? (под свойствами словаря я имею ввиду название_словаря.clear(), название_словаря.copy(), название_словаря.keys() и др. )

Comment: @OMEGA она вернёт словарь python, который имеет все методы словаря. А вообще за это время уже мог сам попробовать и посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо! Последние 2 дня я был за городом, не было возможности попробовать.